# CSS Sprites in IE 7 doesnt work?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-sprites

I want to implement the bullet style for each unordered list.I have the sprite image for that.And I implemented it.I took the example form the below link.
http://www.cssbakery.com/2012/08/css-list-with-icon-sprites.html

It works fine except in IE7.The same tutorial I want to run in IE7 also.How can I achieve it?

```
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>

    <title>CSS Sprites for Bullets</title>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style>
    div
    {
        width:30%;
        float:left;

    }
    .bullet {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin:0; padding:0;
    }

    .bullet li 
    {
            // padding-top: 5px;  
             padding-left: 20px;
             //margin-bottom: 15px;
             //line-height:1.5em;
             //position: relative;
    }
    .magento li:before 
    {
         display: inline-block;
         position: absolute;
         margin: 9px 0 0 -20px;
         min-height: 9px;  
         background: url(images/bulletsprite.png) no-repeat -116px 0px;
         content:"";
        // vertical-align: middle;
         width: 9px; 
         height: 9px;
         float:left;
    }
           </style>
     </head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>Magenta</p>
    <ul class="magento bullet">
        <li>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nulla sapien, varius id dignissim sit amet, luctus elementum nulla. Mauris hendrerit tincidunt nunc condimentum accumsan. Donec semper hendrerit ligula non blandit. Nullam tellus lacus, dictum quis sodales id, consectetur posuere nunc. Maecenas massa nibh, sagittis quis hendrerit ornare, interdum sit amet tellus. Proin lectus neque, posuere at interdum vitae, eleifend id dui. Mauris eget eros magna, sed gravida quam. 
        </li>
        <li>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nulla sapien, varius id dignissim sit amet, luctus elementum nulla. Mauris hendrerit tincidunt nunc condimentum accumsan. Donec semper hendrerit ligula non blandit. Nullam tellus lacus, dictum quis sodales id, consectetur posuere nunc. Maecenas massa nibh, sagittis quis hendrerit ornare, interdum sit amet tellus. Proin lectus neque, posuere at interdum vitae, eleifend id dui. Mauris eget eros magna, sed gravida quam. 
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>  
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: try using the background-image: property instead of background:  .  You'll also have to do a background-repeat:no-repeat and not include the repeat part in the background-image: part.  Ie is finicky sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE7 does not support the `:before` pseudo selector, so the majority of those styles will not work.

See the `:before`/`:after` [browser support chart](http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/).

You can use [IE8.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) to make `:before` work in IE7.

Before test page: http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/before.html

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: +1. it was only introduced in IE8. You can't use this technique in IE7. My advice: Don't waste any more time supporting IE7; the four people in the world still using it as their main browser won't care one way or the other.

Comment: @svk - heh. I was busy writing an answer myself pointing to that script. I'll stop since you got there first. IE8.js is an impressive script, and will solve the problem here. However, I stand by my previous comment that it's not worth the effort given how few IE7 users there are these days.

Comment: @Zak Angelle its not working even after I included the js file from the above lin.Any idea ?